# Will installing p4v also install p4 command line?

Tags: macos, perforce, p4v

I have installed p4v on my Mac. However, I also want to use the p4 command line. Should anything else be installed additionally?

Note : I can't find the p4 binary using locate or using the command `sudo find / -type f | grep p4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply go to ftp.perforce.com and download the p4 binary. Since you are on Mac OS X, you probably want the darwinx86_64 version.

Put it in a folder that is in your path (echo $PATH) and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I copied the p4 binary to /usr/local/bin and also made the file executable. `chmod +x p4`.